Do Dharma Shastras point the way to achieve Moksha or are they mostly concerned with organizing secular society?
An HSE poster writes

Hence it is immaterial if Dharma Sastras have guidelines on anything. Hindus are not obliged to follow them if they exist.

This poster obviously thinks Dharma shastras are not pointers to achieve Moksha.
What does scripture say about the utility of Dharma shastras in achieving Moksha?

Dharma Shastras are about social codes. The laws that govern the Hindu society. How Hindus should behave. It is not primarily related to Moksha. For moksha, you have moksha shastras, i.e., shad-darshanas.

@AmritenduMukhopadhyay the actual question is is it necessary to follow the teaching of Dharma sastras to attain moksha

@CracklingCyclone The answer is obvious! As Dharmasastras are not about moksha, and there is a separate and dedicated branch of sastras for moksha, it is not necessary to follow dharmasastra to attain moksha!

Without proper societal conduct, you are just a problem for others. The Dharmashastras help us know this proper societal conduct, therefore following them should be necessary for Parmārtha, imo

Dharma Sastras deal primarily with societal issues and the problem is that many of their views are obsolete. Some of their views were rejected in Hindu scripture many centuries ago. I have given below the attitude towards women in Manu Smriti.
EXAMPLE of rejection


Her father protects (her) in childhood, her husband protects (her) in youth, and her sons protect (her) in old age; a woman is never fit
for independence.


Manu Smriti 9.3
Polemicists have a great day attacking Manu Smriti 9.3 and establishing Sanatana Dharma as misogynistic. They, however, never point out that there is an opposite view expressed in Hindu scripture on the very same topic.

Devi Bhagavata Purana V.XVII
The lady Mandodari refuses to marry because she refuses to accept dependence. Some of Dharma Sutra views were obsolete even 1000 years ago.
